# Symfony design question - how can I share forms between apps?

Tags: forms, symfony1

I'm developing a site in Symfony, and I'm not sure what the best way is to handle this scenario.

I'm creating a party bookings system. Anyone can go to my frontend app and submit a new booking. Once they're finished, they'll just get a confirmation screen, they can't edit it. Easy.

Only certain users will be able to get to the admin app (it might be secured simply by being on an intranet, but that's not important, just assume it will be only accessible by admin users). They'll be able to view the list of submitted bookings. Easy.

My problem is around code re-use when allowing admin users to edit existing bookings. When you do `generate-module` in Symfony, the generated module (which as a newbie I'm assuming is a good example of structuring things) creates the form as a partial. I've had to customize this form a lot for my usage (lots of Javascript, etc), so of course I want to re-use this code, to be able to load an existing booking into this form. But there doesn't seem to be a way to share this partial between the apps (I've seen people mention making a plugin...but this seems complicated for this use).

I considered using an IFrame to load the form from the frontend and just passing an "id" parameter to load it in edit mode, but this would mean that the edit mode is not secure - anyone could go to the form on the frontend and pass this parameter to edit a booking.

I also considered putting all of the form display code (HTML, Javascript, etc) in a method on the form object, but this doesn't seem very MVC - all of the display code is then in the form. But this is only because I'm thinking of the form in the same way as a model - is that right?

I feel like this should be a common situation. You can share models and forms between apps, why can't you share this common form display code too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider having 2 applications in the first place. Not only you run into the code reuse problem, but also i18n, testings and other issues. I find it much easier to have 1 application with different bunch of modules for frontend and backend users. You can configure security per module. You can have one sign in form for all users and redirect them to appropriate module based on their credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse partials between modules inside the same application, but you seem to be talking about two different applications (frontend and backend) so as far as i know the only way is to copy & paste the partial from one application to the other...